# Unable to rotate GameObject properly?

Tags: c#, unity

My GameObject is able to jump towards a moving target (another GameObject), thus adjusting its trajectory - while simulating gravity (as in the .gif).

[image: .gif]

I want to make the "jumper object" rotate. But I am unable to rotate my GameObject properly. When the GameObject jumps, it doesn't complete its rotation and rotates abruptely. How can I fix this? How can I properly rotate the cube GameObject you see in the .gif? Any fixes are appreciated.

Wanted rotation:

[image: Wanted rotation]

What I get:

[image: what I get]

Comment: Image is not available for me. But i guess GetMouseButtonUp couses problems. Try GetMouseButton instead. So your object will turn constantly while you press button, not only when you relase it.

Comment: Image now available.

Comment: "don't cooperate very well" is super vague. tell us what is happening

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @TheGameChanger I guess what you want to do is making cube to look forward vector of it's current position on trajectory right? As far as i can see, you already calculate velocity vector in your `jumpAndFollow` method. Then you can simply use this: `transform.LookAt(transform.position + velocityVector.normalized);` This will make your gameObject's +z axis to line on the vector you give in paranthesis.

Comment: Question edited again! :)

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN Can you write an answer, because what you're saying is not very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The code structure you want:**

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, lerpFactor);
```

**A more adjusted version for your script:**

Change the line

```
transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (a, b, c) * Time.deltaTime);
```

with

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(a, b, c), Time.deltaTime);
```

**Also,**

```
        void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                //this is only called when button gets relased.
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
            {
                //this is called constantly if button is holding down.
            }
        }
```

---

**Edit:**

This code piece should do what you want:

```
    Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.identity; //try not to modify this directly, or do it, it's up to you.
    bool doRotate = false;
    float lerpLimit = 10; //the degrees you want lerp to stop at. set higher than 0 (i suggest higher than 1)

    public void SetRotationTarget(Vector3 eulerAngles) //call this method to update the rotation target.
    {
        targetRot = Quaternion.Euler (eulerAngles); //building a quaternion from given vector3
        doRotate = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (doRotate)
        {
            if (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRot) > lerpLimit) //if angle between our rotation and target rotation is not below limit
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRot, Time.deltaTime); //Slerp to target rotation
            }
            else
            {
                transform.rotation = targetRot;
                doRotate = false;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) //when mouse button 0 is relased
        {
            SetRotationTarget(new Vector3(a, b, c)); //set new rotation target with values of (a, b, c)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't lerp! Same problem. Exactly.

Comment: @TheGameChanger Take a look at the edit.

Comment: Let's say I have `transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 180) * Time.deltaTime); ` How do I convert it with your most recent edit? Where do I put the numbers?

Comment: Just write an example with numbers in your answer. (or a, b, c)

Comment: @TheGameChanger Revised the edit.

Comment: Still the same issue. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: And you made a mistake, it should be like this: `if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
  {
   if (transform.rotation != targetRot) 
   {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRot, Time.deltaTime);
   }
   SetRotationTarget(new Vector3(0, 0, 180)); 
  }`

Comment: @TheGameChanger I can't help you anymore, seems like i don't understand what you want, and you don't know that either. I suggest you to check out your algorithm first before starting to code them down. Also, what you wrote just spams object to same rotation all the time, because you call  SetRotationTarget   in all Update's.

Comment: Did you try copy/pasting my scripts in your Unity editor?

Comment: @TheGameChanger I can estimate what will happen. I'm familiar with lerps. If you want to do this the way you wrote, just delete everything and lerp directly, you don't have to use a temporary quaternion for target rotation. And, i wonder why you want to use lerp if you want rotation to be updated for only one frame?

Comment: Maybe the .gif's script is interfering with your script. Maybe we just need to add something in the .gif's script, but I don't know what...

Comment: With your most recent edit, the GameObject rotates without `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`

Comment: @TheGameChanger I think you miss the point of Lerp functions. They work with time, not in a single frame. You need to call them until the result you want. If you call them just one frame, it is the identical to update value manually by `(prevValue + targetValue)/(2*totalSteps)`.

Comment: But, your code does not make the GameObject rotate when `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) ` It rotates immediately when we run the game. I want to rotate **only** when `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) `

Comment: @TheGameChanger I edited again. I think it now perfectly fits what you need.

Comment: How do I make this work properly: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);` `from` is a GameObject at 180° and `to` is a GameObject at 0°. Isn't that simpler? Can you make it work properly please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31534/discussion-between-the-game-changer-and-samed-tarik-cetn).

Comment: I still did not find away. Can you help?

Comment: How do I make this work properly: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);` from is a GameObject at 180° and to is a GameObject at 0°. Isn't that simpler? Can you make it work properly please?

Comment: You can't lerp "from 180 degrees to 0 degrees". You need to add axis information too, in which axis you want this rotation to happen?

Comment: Z axis. But from is a GameObject at x=0, y=0, z=180 (degrees) and to is a  GameObject at  x=0, y=0, z=0. So it's already defined and works very well outside my .gif script.

Comment: In the last script in my answer, replace body of the condition `if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))` with this: `SetRotationTarget(new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, 180)); transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31561/discussion-on-answer-by-samed-tarik-cetn-unable-to-rotate-gameobject-properly).

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand... Here's what I want. I want the functionality of the code in the most recent edit of your answer (which is _This code piece should do what you want:_) But instead of using a lerpLimit, I want to define the speed of rotation. **Basically, I want to rotate from 0 degrees to 180 degrees smoothly at a speed that I can define.** That's it! Thank your for your replies.